# Owl-carousel display alot 3 images per item - Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-8

I just started using owl-carousel and i want to display 3 images per item, so i want to make sure laravel will create an item each 3 img displayed in the slide(".item")

here is my Javascript Code

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            loop:false, // loop over the items
            margin:0,
            items: 6,
            itemsDesktop: [1400, 6],
            itemsDesktopSmall: [1100, 4],
            itemsTablet: [700, 3],
            itemsMobile: [500, 2],
            nav:false, // Display the arrow nav of the carousel
            dots:false, // Display the dot of the carousel
            responsive:{
                0:{ // The width of the screen from 0px to 599px
                    items:2 // How many items you want to display
                },
                600:{ // The width of the screen from 600px to 999 px
                    items:3 // How many items you want to display
                },
                1000:{ // The width of the screen from 1000 px
                    items:4 // How many items you want to display
                }
            }
        })
```

and here is my blade

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" style="margin-left: 20px">
                <div class="item col-md-12">
                    @foreach ($AsignItems as $ItemOwned)
                        <div class="lms-cours-item-list">
                            <img class="img-fluid list-item-img" src="{{ $ItemOwned->image }}" alt="{{ $ItemOwned->log }}" />
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    @foreach ($Diff as $ItemUnowned)
                    <div class="lms-cours-badgs-list unowned-item">
                        <img class="img-fluid list-item-img" src="{{ $ItemUnowned->image }}" alt="{{ $ItemUnowned->alt}}" />
                    </div>
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
```

Can you please tell me should i do to get 3 element per item ?
is there any other option ?

Comment: What you're saying is that you need one .item div with 3 .lms-cours-item-list divs within it? So if you have 9 items in your $AsignItems array, you'd have three .item divs in total and if you have 6 items in your array, you'd have two .item divs and so on...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control how many items will be shown from your js Code:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            loop:false, // loop over the items
            margin:0,
            items: 3,
            itemsDesktop: [1400, 3],
            itemsDesktopSmall: [1100, 3],
            itemsTablet: [700, 3],
            itemsMobile: [500, 2],
            nav:false, // Display the arrow nav of the carousel
            dots:false, // Display the dot of the carousel
            responsive:{
                0:{ // The width of the screen from 0px to 599px
                    items:2 // How many items you want to display
                },
                600:{ // The width of the screen from 600px to 999 px
                    items:3 // How many items you want to display
                },
                1000:{ // The width of the screen from 1000 px
                    items:3 // How many items you want to display
                }
            }
})
```

I think this will work for you. And if you like to scroll the items automatically add this

```
autoplay:true,
```